# Why does python 2.7.2 pygtk segfault parsing a glade GtkButtonBox?

Tags: python, gtk, segmentation-fault, pygtk, glade

Here are the steps to reproduce my problem: I designed a UI in glade 3.10.0 including a GtkButtonBox containing 4 buttons:

```
<object class="GtkButtonBox" id="i_bbox">
<property name="visible">True</property>
[...] some children (buttons)
```

The glade file gets loaded into the python script:

```
builder_fname = "example_layout.glade"
self.root = gtk.Builder()
self.root.add_from_file(builder_fname)
self.root.connect_signals(self)
```

When the script gets executed, it segfaults with the following traceback:

```
./example.py:37: Warning: cannot create instance of abstract (non-instantiatable) type `GtkButtonBox'
self.root.add_from_file(builder_fname)
[1]    5088 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./example.py
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this? I'm using pygtk 2.24.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning seems to hint that you need to use GtkHButtonBox or GtkVButtonBox versus GtkButtonBox ... do those segfault?

Comment: I haven't found any way to select the Gtk(H,V)ButtonBox in Glade, when I try to edit the glade file w/ Glade v3.8, glade crashes...

Comment: When modified the glade file manually the script does not segfault but the window which should contain the buttonbox doesn't appear and doesn't print an error msg either ...

Comment: How strange.  When I used Glade 3, it wouldn't let me not pick H|V ButtonBox (didn't see an option of a generic buttonBox even in the obsolete widgets list).  If it's not overly long, I'd suggest posting the whole glade file (Edit: glade 3.6.3 to be specific)

Comment: The problem is, that pygtk does not yet support gtk3 files yet which are produced by glade 3.10.0 :( I'll have to recreate the whole file w/ glade 3.8, dammit... https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654706

Comment: Glade 3.10 should have an option (in the "Project properties" or some such dialog) that allows you to select compatibility with 2.x GTK versions.

Comment: Yes, there's a dialog under File->Properties which gives you some options for the lowest required gtk version but seems not to change anything but this. When I press validate on the current 2.24 pygtk ver (and any other) selectable, glade reports no deprecated widgets and no errors at all. But pygtk still segfaults, as well as glade 3.8 does... And that's "NOTABUG" but a entire programmer failure the developers of pygtk say, not theirs... c'mon